# why checked checkbox higher than unchecked in visualforce table

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I what to sort table by field Order Number:[Check List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qKNE.png)

I have a WrapperClass which implements interface Comparable:

```
public class CheckListWrapper implements Comparable
{
    public Boolean isChecked {get; set;}
    public String shortDescription {get; set;}
    public String fullDescription {get; set;}
    public Integer order {get; set;}
    public CheckList__c checkList;
    public CheckListItem__c checkListItem;

    public CheckListWrapper(CheckList__c chList)
    {
        shortDescription = chList.Short_Description__c;
        fullDescription = chList.Full_Description__c;
        order = (Integer)chList.Order__c;
        isChecked = false;
        checkList = chList;
    }

    public CheckListWrapper(CheckListItem__c chListItem)
    {
        shortDescription = chListItem.CheckList__r.Short_Description__c;
        fullDescription = chListItem.CheckList__r.Full_Description__c;
        order = (Integer)chListItem.CheckList__r.Order__c;
        isChecked = true;
        checkListItem = chListItem;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo)
    {
        CheckListWrapper compareToCheckList = (CheckListWrapper)compareTo;
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (checkList != null)
        {
            if (checkList.Order__c > compareToCheckList.checkList.Order__c)
            {
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (checkList.Order__c < compareToCheckList.checkList.Order__c)
            {
                returnValue = -1;
            }
        } else if (checkListItem != null)
        {
            if (checkListItem.CheckList__r.Order__c > compareToCheckList.checkListItem.CheckList__r.Order__c)
            {
                returnValue = 1;
            } else if (checkListItem.CheckList__r.Order__c < compareToCheckList.checkListItem.CheckList__r.Order__c)
            {
                returnValue = -1;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Interface comparable works but all checked checkboxes are higher than unchecked. 
The question is why checked checkboxes are higher than unchecked and how could be avoided it?

Answer (score 0):

Well. I understood my mistake: Everything is alright, but I had should used one block if else in the method compareTo and don't reference to field Order__c through the Object CheckList__c. I had should used "order" variable from CheckListWrapper:

```
public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo)
    {
        CheckListWrapper compareToCheckList = (CheckListWrapper)compareTo;
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (order > compareToCheckList.order)
        {
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (order < compareToCheckList.order)
        {
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```